# importing "process.env" in angular2-meteor application

Tags: angular, meteor, process, angular2-meteor

I am working on angular2-meteor project and I have used MailGun which can be implement or used by `process.env.Mail_URL` like this 
`process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://example@example.com';`. It's working but I am getting error that:

> cannot fine name 'process'

so how can I import it?

I have tried to import it in `typing.d.ts` file but it also won't work, so how will it work? How to import it? and what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's working and your problem is only Typescript complaining , you could do :

```
declare var process:any;
```

At the top of your file that uses process.

Comment: thanks for the answer... Its worked without any error, thanks again for the answer...